# Pressing Spacebar scrolls down: how do I prevent this?

Tags: keyboard

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer Aspire-E5-575G laptop and I am having problems with my spacebar: when I press the spacebar, the page scrolls down, and I'm not sure how to fix this. It does not happen if I am typing in a text box. Only when I'm on a page and I press the spacebar and then boom, I've scrolled down quite a bit.

Thanks for your help

edit: I am talking about in the browser. If this is a normal feature I have never noticed it before. The reason I noticed it was because I was on this site (http://thetypingcat.com/typing-speed-test/1m) and when I pressed the spacebar it scrolled down the page rather than to the next word, and I don't recall that happening before I installed Ubuntu.

edit 2: This appears to be normal behavior that is specific to google chrome because when I use Firefox on the same website the problem does not exist anymore.

Comment: Pressing spacebar has scrolled web pages since forever. I think that even Mosaic had this. A browser which *didn't* implement this feature would be considered exceedingly weird.

Comment: You say that this behaviour occurs *even when the focus is on and the cursor in a text field*. I presume you're talking about a web browser. Which one? Does this happen on all (tested) web sites (with text fields) or only some and, if so, which ones? Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Is the same thing occurring on different websites? If not, I'd guess it's specific to that website...

Comment: I made some edits above. Apparently, it's a google chrome thing because the problem doesn't exist with firefox.

Comment: Or your site is messing with text input fields in a way that confuses Chrome. Some sites so that; trying to create "rich" text editors with broken JavaScript.

Comment: @brff19 firefox does this too when I press spacebar. And so does MSIE 11 and Edge.